#  Cannot find yasm even though I have installed it 

Tags: linux, x264, yasm

I got a strange problem. I tried to install x264. When run sudo ./configure --enable-shared, 
it gave:

**Found no assembler
Minimum version is yasm-0.7.0
If you really want to compile without asm, configure with --disable-asm.**

But I already installed yasm-0.7.0 ,to prove that ,i run yasm --version,it gave:

****yasm 0.7.0.2066
Compiled on May  8 2012.
Copyright (c) 2001-2008 Peter Johnson and other Yasm developers.
Run yasm --license for licensing overview and summary.****

I install yasm to /usr/local/yasm,
Why can it not find yasm?

Comment: @zhen_lee I believe my answer is correct. If you agree, could you please mark it as such?

Answer (score 12):

Just in case of someone got here from Google, looking for a recent solution.

Recent versions of x264 moved from yasm to nasm, hence breaking some FFMPEG install scripts or tutorials. To check if it is the case, look at the output. If it reads

```
Minimum version is nasm-2.13
```

then you are to install nasm. In Ubuntu 16.04 repos there's nasm 2.11; so you'll have to build from sources, following official instruction http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/nasm.html.

Answer (score 8):

`sudo` ignores your `PATH` environment variable and uses its own.

compare:

```
$ which yasm
/usr/local/bin/yasm
```

with:

```
$ sudo which yasm
/usr/bin/yasm
```

To solve, do:

```
$ sudo PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin which yasm
/usr/local/bin/yasm
```

or rather

```
$ sudo PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin ./configure --enable-shared
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are  running Ubuntu and if "which yasm " results in nothing Please try out the below mentioned command for building the x64....

sudo apt-get install yasm

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you have an old version of yasm on your system, so you should update it! see here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Quick/libx264

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should rebuild the yasm for the correct path /usr/bin/yasm.

Comment: `/usr/bin` is not the correct/conventional path for locally built software. It's typically placed in `/usr/local/bin` to avoid overwriting/mixing files that were installed by the system's package manager. Mixing/overwriting can otherwise wreak havoc.

Comment: @Catskul You're right. I just find out that the yasm is installed in the /usr/bin dirs by default.